# Generate a queryset from ForeignKey values

Tags: django-queryset, python-3.4, django-1.9

I'm at a lost here. I need to generate a queryset (*qs*) composed of the values pointed by foreign keys of another *qs* (looked for it here, got bald in the process...).

Now, let's say I have the simple models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_field="comments")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's comment"%self.user.name
```

What I have is a *qs* composed of (a lot of) specifically selected **Comments**. Say:

`[<Comment: "user_A's comment">,<Comment: "user_B's comment">,...]`

And I need to generate a *qs* composed of **Users**, from the values pointed by my previous *qs*'s foreign keys. Now, I cant just use `values('user')` to get a list, because the resulting *qs* has to execute further operations in the *db*, such as joining with other Users *qs*, filtering, etc.

I also tried to brute force the process by using `.raw()` with some success, but then I get a rawQuerySet object, which I can't use either.

Looking at the documentation about `extra()` and `select_related()` stuff, I thought there might be a way somehow, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After trying stuff around, I found a way to do exactly what I want. Although the approach may be a bit inefficient since the *db* has to be hit multiple times, the result is in the right format (a queryset). For those who encounter the same issue, here's the way to generate a queryset of *users* from values pointed by foreignkeys, given another queryset of, say, *comments*:

```
some_users_queryset = User.objects.filter(comments__pk__in=some_comments_queryset)
some_users_queryset = some_users_queryset.distinct()
```

As I said, I dont think this way is the most efficient, but I would like to limit my use of pure SQL while playing around with Django.

Of course I would love to hear about a better, quicker way to achieve the same result.